# Issue Tracker for Building applications

Tags: tortoisesvn

We currently have an existing issue tracker, which the service management team utilise for logging user reported issues.

What I would like to do is create a server based (probably web-ui) system that can query the issue tracker for bugs assigned to the dev team and if the Impacted file is ready to be build then the Build can be triggered from the Issue tracker such that checkout from the SVN repository,uploading the code on the build server and finally building it happens in an automated manner.How to start about it?

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach works like that:

- Install a central build server (Hudson, Jenkins, Bamboo, ...).
- Configure a build job there that has a trigger to start the build when a commit is done by a developer.
- The build is then done, and as a result, all tickets that are named in the commit message are listed for the build.
- When a build is then taken to a test environment, you may look at the build result to see which tickets are resolved by the build.

We have that installed in numerous development environments, e.g. with the following software used:

- Trac with Subversion
- JIRA, Subversion, Hudson
- Polarion, build management in Polarion, Subversion
- ...

You need a configuration management as one of the components to work.

Answer (score 1):

look into SVN hook scripts. you're probably better off trying to do builds from a hook script than trying to do them from an integrated issue tracker.
you can write a post-commit hook script to:
look up the comment for the revision just committed.
parse the comment for a keyword (something like "build" or "fixed").
then based on the detection of this keword this script can then kick off an svn-update on your build machine, then your build script. [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) seems like a good (although insecure) way to run the svn update and build script from the SVN server on the build machine. this is how i have been thinking of implementing automatic builds for my own team, i just havnt gotten time to write the scripts yet though.

Comment: can you please provide any code for the Post-Commit hook script?..That would be helpful

Comment: as i mentioned, i haven't gotten a chance to write the actual script yet. it all seems very possible in a bat file though. probably the hardest part will be parsing the comment for a keyword. the rest will be specific to what tools you use to develop. for example, to build a project in visual studio you would put something like this in your script
"devenv /build release myproject\myproject.sln"